# How do I custom lazyload on both text and images with animation?

Tags: html, jquery, css, lazy-loading

I need to make a lazyload that actually works like one that is in Facebook. I created a css class that has this.

```
    @keyframes placeholder {
      0% { background-position: -600px 0 }
      100% { background-position: 600px 0 }
    }
    .text-loader{
      color: transparent !important;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-name: placeholder;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      background: #eeeeee;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #eee 8%, #419AF3 18%, #eee 33%);
      background-size: 1200px 100px;
      min-height: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
      border-radius: 3px;
      &::selection{
        color: transparent;
      }
    }
```

And wrote some scripts to make it look like it actually works.

```
      var agalar = $("span, p, h1, h2, h3");
      $(".contents").find(agalar).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("text-loader");
      });
      $(window).on("load",function(){
      $(agalar).removeClass("text-loader");
      });
```

Everything "seems" to work but I am not sure if it actually works. (I am making an infinite scrolling section so I guess will need to pull content from back-end), the thing is how can I make this a real lazyload?

Comment: Well, this is not lazy loading. 

The basic way to implement lazy loading is using ajax.

E.g. use the window onscroll event to check for scroll location and when the scroll position is at the bottom of the page call an ajax function to retrieve more data. For instance, you can display 1st 5 posts, and then when the user scrolls down to the bottom pull more 5 post using ajax.

If you can give more information on how you plan to pull your data from the backend, we can look more on the implementation end

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use Ajax like you said it. My backend dev friend help me on this situation. Is there anything else I can do as front-end?

Comment: @ErenGelgeç I would search Google for Jquery Infinite Scroll and download a plugin since there are many plugins. In your case there really isn't a need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @imvain2 Absolutely true but the thing is I need to make it look like Facebook's 
https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/ZEBorVx
like this one.
Is there any plugins that let's me built this looking like loading?